# applying Ito's lemma to complex logarithm

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

This is a question I got while reading the proof of Lemma 4 from the following post: https://almostsuremath.com/2010/06/16/continuous-processes-with-independent-increments/

Here, let $X$ be a continuous $d$-dimensional process with independent increments and $\psi:\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{C}$ be the unique continuous function with $\psi(0,a)=0$ and $$E[e^{ia\cdot (X_t - X_0)}]=e^{\psi(t,a)}.$$ Then we know that $e^{ia\cdot X_t - \psi(t,a)}$ is a martingale for each fixed $a\in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Now, set $Y_t = ia\cdot (X_t - X_0) - \psi_t(a)$. Then, $U:= \exp(Y)$ is the martingale $e^{ia\cdot X_t - \psi(t,a)}$, and hence a semimartingale.

The author then says that by Ito's lemma, $Y=\log(U)$ is a semimartingale.

From the Ito's lemma statement the author gives, this requires $U$ to take values in some open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ on which $\log$ is twice differentiable. For complex logarithms, this would be the case if $U$ takes values in $\mathbb{C}$ minus some branch cut. But how do we ensure this?

The author just states that there is no problem in applying Ito's lemma here because although the logarithm is not a well-defined twice differentiable function everywhere on $\mathbb{C}^\times$, this is true locally (actually, on any half plane).

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could explain how the domain of the complex logarithm does not become an issue here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is a bit late in the day therefore just a naive thought: when he defines $Y_t=ia(X_t-X_0)-\psi_t(a)$ knowing that $X_t$ is continuous with independent increments and $\psi_t(a)$ is continuous is that not enough to see that $Y$ is a semimartingale? I don't see why that log is even needed.

Comment: @KurtG. The author is trying to show that $X_t $ is a semimartingale using Ito's lemma.

Comment: IMHO he does not have to. We know that $X_t$ is a semimartingale (see my first comment). What the author is trying to show in that Lemma 4 where this proof is from is that $ia\cdot (X_t-X_0)-\psi_t(a)-\frac{1}{2}[a\cdot\tilde{X}]_t$ is a square integrable martingale.

Comment: @KurtG. Why is $X_t$ a  semimartingale?

Comment: $X_t$ is continuous and has independent increments. It is therefore a Levy process. Lowther shows [here](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/11/23/levy-processes/) that it is then a semimartingale.

Comment: @KurtG. This is a post after the one I posted here. And indeed the theorem you linked to refers to Lemma 6 from this post https://almostsuremath.com/2010/09/15/processes-with-independent-increments/#scn_ind_thm2 and it has the same argument of applying Ito's lemma to the complex logarithm. As he is using the same argument repeatedly I am more curious as to why this argument holds.

Answer (score 0):

> The author then says that by Itô's lemma, $Y=\log(U)$ is a semimartingale. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could explain how the domain of the complex logarithm does not become an issue here.

We will do the Itô expansion for $t_{0}$ and $t_{0}+h$ i.e. we want to show that

$$Y_{t_{0}+h}=Y_{t_{0}}+semimartingale.$$

The process $U_{t}\equiv\exp(Y_{t})=\exp(ia\cdot (X_t-X_0)-\psi_t(a))\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ is continuous for $t\geq 0$ and so for small enough $h>0$ there exists a complex ball $B_{r_{0}}(U_{t_0})$  such that
$$(U_{t})_{t\in [t_{0},t_{0}+h]}\subset B_{r_{0}}(U_{t_0})\text{ and }0\notin B_{r_{0}}(U_{t_0}).$$

Then we define our principal logarithm $Log$ to have a branch connecting zero to infinity that avoids this ball. Away from the branch we have infinitely many derivatives and so we can apply the Itô-formula to the real and imaginary parts separately.

For general $t,t+s$, we first need to partition $[t,t+s]=\bigsqcup_{k} I_{h_{k}}$ and then apply the above argument repeatedly.